# PHP if Statement mysqli_num_rows not working

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have a code which asks if a row exists in a database and if it does, it will echo a message. However, nothing is echoed no matter what input I put in.

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<body>

  <?php

    $mysqlhost="host";
    $mysqldatabase="b33_15887129_Accounts";
    $mysqlusername="username";
    $mysqlpassword="password";
    $connect=new mysqli($mysqlhost,$mysqlusername,$mysqlpassword);

    if (!$connect) {
      die("Connection failed: " . $connect->connect_error);
    }

    echo "Connected Successfully";

    mysqli_select_db($connect,"b33_15887129_Accounts");
    $loginusername=$_POST['loginusername'];
    $loginpassword=$_POST['loginpassword'];
    $checkifexist="SELECT * FROM Users WHERE Username='$loginusername' AND 'Password=$loginpassword'";
    $runquery=mysqli_query($connect,$checkifexist);
    $numofrows=mysqli_num_rows($runquery);

    if($numofrows==1){
      echo "Successfully logged in!";
    }else{
      echo "Failed to log in";
    }

  ?>
</body>
</html>
```

It manages to echo `Connected successfully` but `Successfully logged in` and `Failed to log in` does not appear no matter what the input. Any help?

Comment: `'Password=$loginpassword'` . It should be correct like this , `Password='$loginpassword'`

Comment: Mind screams in terror at plaintext passwords on the database, in horror at injecting $_POST values directly into a SQL statement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your "failed to log in" isn't displaying because you've forgotten the echo.

```
if($numofrows==1){
    echo "Successfully logged in!";
}
else{
    echo "Failed to log in";

}
```

In order to get the sql to work, @Ranjith is correct, you'll need to alter the quote placement in your sql statement.

Comment: OK, I changed everything. Now it just says Failed to log in even though I clearly have a database with a row that fulfills all the requirements.

Comment: If you run the same select statement within the database does it return a row? If it does, then something about your sql statement is incorrect. An easy test would be to hard code the values that you need into the sql - so Username = 'test' AND password = 'test' and see whether that brings back the correct response.

Answer (score 0):

1) Your else statement have no echo !!!

2) Your SQL Statement is wrong! Check the quotes at the password! --> Password='$loginpassword'

In fact you should have a look at http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php.